# Removing shadow from selected UITTAB in UITABBAR

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I had a question. How do you customise the uitabbar so that you can remove the shadow gradient you get on the selected item in the tabbar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways of doing that, one is explained [here](http://blog.theanalogguy.be/2010/10/06/custom-colored-uitabbar-icons/) and is a bit hackish, the other is implementing your own tab bar, with fully customizable icons. if you google "customize uitabbarcontroller" you will find several basic implementations of it. You can find one such implementation [here](http://didikot.com/?p=106).

Comment: Yeah those are the ones I found (the sources) but they didn't seem elegant to me at all. Just was wondering if anyone came up with any more innovative solution. Thanks though mate Ill leave this open for a while before closing if yo udon't mind

Comment: no problem about leaving it open... Just a question: I easily understand you don't like the first approach, but what do you exactly find not elegant with the second? Is it the code or the approach about building a whole new tab bar in order just to remove the icon shadowing?

Comment: I implemented a custom UITabBar and I still have this gradient/shadow on top of it. What am I doing wrong ? Is there anything to specify to get rid of it ?